# Dll issue while launching the application

Tags: c++, c++11, c++builder

[image] I am using one dll in my application for including the functionality provided by that dll . This dll i am getting after  installing one msi .
But in my application i have  a requirement like if the user has not installed that msi then we have to show one warning message(e.g msi has not installed , code for this i have implemented in the main() of my application ) and have to exit from the application .

But the problem is if the user has not installed the msi , then while launching the application itself its showing one error message since its not able to get the dll  and this time  control not even coming to my main() where i have written the code for this msi checking  (through registry entry).

Is there any efficient way to resolve this issue ..

Comment: So you're saying your `main()` isn't executed when you don't have the dll? We are speaking about `main()` and not `DllMain()`, right?

Comment: yes . what i want is even if the dll is not present , the code which i have written in my int main(){...} , should get executed . But as i have mentioned above the control is not even coming to my main() , since it showing the problem during launching the application .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider delay-loading the DLL (Project -> Options -> Advanced Linker).

This will allow your app to load when the DLL is missing.

Comment: But in this case i am getting the fatal error for respective .lib file ..is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: @vivek What is the exact error in this case? .lib files are usually linked into the executable, so I would not expect to see a runtime error about a .lib file.